# KeyError and AttributeError in Stripe API call

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am trying to print out the subscriptions of a customer in stripe.
I am using

```
import stripe 
from flask import ... 
...
stripe.api_key = os.environ['STRIPE_KEY']

customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve('cus_*******')
print(customer.subscriptions)
```

I am receiving the errors

```
KeyError: 'subscriptions' 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occured:
AttributeError: subscriptions
```

When I run `print(customer)`, the output matches `THE CUSTOMER OBJECT` response [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object). When I query values that are within that initial response, such as `print(customer.address)`, `print(customer.currency)`, or `print(customer.name)`, these show. But, when I query values that are not within that initial response, such as `print(customer.cash_balance)`, `print(customer.tax.location)` or `print(customer.subscriptions)`, I keep receiving the same error

```
KeyError: '* *'

AttributeError: * *
```

I am confused because `customer.subscriptions`, `customer.tax`, and `customer.cash_balance` are listed under **More attributes**, so they seem to be valid things to call. Anyways any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are missing the POST parameter with the response from the documentation you posted there is no subscription inside the response body. i think you will have to query it seperatly

Answer (score 0):

Although through the rest of my answer you will learn how to populate the `subscriptions` fields, a better way to retrieve a customer's subscriptions. Instead you should use the Subscriptions [List](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer) API and filter by Customer ID.

As for the other fields you are referring to, as a general rule, in the API docs if a property (e.g. `cash_balance`) is followed by `Expandable` this means that by default it is not included in the response unless you add it to the `expand` parameter. If you want to learn more about expansion you can visit this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) or refer to the API [section](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) about expanding objects. Note that when the expandable object references another Stripe Object (e.g. `test_clock` on the Customer [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-test_clock)) you will receive the object ID if you don't expand whereas for inline objects (e.g. `cash_balance` or `tax` in the customer) they get returned as null.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! Didn't make the connection with the expand parameter..